# Lego Robot for collecting table tennis balls

Tags: java, lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I have a goal to build a robot that can collect table tennis balls and put them into the goals A and B seen to the left and right side of the added picture. For info, the course is rectangular with one single obstacle; a four-walled cross.

For now I have bought the Pixy 2 to recognize the balls it needs to pick up.

My two questions are:

1. Is Lego Mindstorm (LM) an easy/reasonable programming language to solve this, and can LM also easily control the robot’s movements?
2. Is it possible to use Java instead of LM to solve this? (This would be preferred, as I know Java but not LM)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As I understand LM is not a programming language and you can use several software kits to deploy a program on the LM. Some of them are Java based.

See 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Mindstorms

Answer (score 0):

1. Lego Mindstorm's default programming language is visual/blocks based. It's intended for kids with not programming experience. So, if you know Java you'll have no problem using it. Indeed you'll find it too simple.
   Programming a robot's movement is very easy, and it comes as a sample project in the Mindstorm's set.
   Plus: Your camera comes with [plugins to add it's own block to the Mindstorms programming environment](https://pixycam.com/pixy2-lego/). You even have a [sample project to build a chaser robot](https://docs.pixycam.com/wiki/doku.php?id=wiki:v2:lego_chase_demo).
2. From my experience (with Mindstorms NXT2) trying to use [LeJOS](http://www.lejos.org/)() was not straightforward. But that was several years ago, with an older version you've indicated in the tags (`ev3`).